# Is there any way to dynamically create excel file in bot framework?

Tags: excel, azure, botframework

I am using bot framework. I want to create an excel file in bot framework to display some table which is the output of some BI type question like "what is the revenue of product x in previous year?"

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a CSV file by using trivial code, or use a .NET library like `spreadsheetlight` in order to generate an Excel file.

Then you can attach the newly generated Excel file as an attachment to your bot's message.

Services like Facebook are OK with your bot sending PDF or Excel files. In an IDialog you would use it like this:

```
private async Task SendAttachmentToUser(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        string incoming = await argument;

        //this is your method that generates excel file and returns a link to it
        var excelLink = GenerateExcelFileBasedOnUserQuery(incoming.Text);

        IMessageActivity response = context.MakeMessage();
        response.Attachments = new List<Attachment>()
        {
            new Attachment()
            {
                ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                ContentUrl = "http://yoursuperbot.azurewebsites.net/Files/2843578193485719fa011.xls",
                Name = "Your_Results.xls"
            }
        };
        response.Text = "Here are your results.";
        await context.PostAsync(response);
        context.Done(this);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help.My bot is in azure and i am unable to create my file inside bot framework directory but it works locally. So, do i need to have access to my file system in azure (i have trial subscription only.).

Comment: Still unable to create file. In your code , from where you were creating 2843578193485719fa011.xls file insides http://yoursuperbot.azurewebsites.net/Files/. Can you please share the code.